# A current source with PMOS

Tags: mosfet, current-source

I created a voltage-controlled current source with PMOS.

By changing Vg and Vd, I get the below curves.

Vg is the controlled voltage. Vd is the source voltage.

As we can see from the graph, the Vd can affect the current at a given Vg.

How do I modify this circuit so the current is independent from Vd? The reason I want Vd to be irrelevant to the current is that I need to measure the voltage at the node Vd at a given current, where node Vd is connecting to other circuity which is not shown here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: _" the reason I want Vd to be irrelevant to the current is that I need to measure the voltage at the node Vd at a given current"_ - so you want a constant current **sink**. Therefore, why are you using a PMOS FET?

Answer (score 2):

A good sink source ... must use an op-amp ...

Something as this.
NB: R5 100 W, needed for high current (> 5 A). Multiple IRF540 paralleled.
Value of R5 lower ( <= 0.1 Ohm)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of, using a MOSFET, is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGaSo9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The zener diode keeps gate potential at:

$$ V_G = V_{SUPPLY} - 4.7 $$

The MOSFET is a source follower, which keeps the voltage at its source S slightly greater than its gate G, the difference being the MOSFET's threshold voltage \$V_{TH}\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_S &= V_G + V_{TH} \\ \\
&= V_{SUPPLY} - 4.7  + V_{TH} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The voltage across R1 is therefore:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} &= V_{SUPPLY} - V_S \\ \\
&= V_{SUPPLY} - \left(V_{SUPPLY} - 4.7  + V_{TH}\right) \\ \\
&= 4.7 - V_{TH}
\end{aligned}
$$

The current through R1, which must all be sunk into the load RL is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{R1} &= \frac{V_{R1}}{R_1} \\ \\
&= \frac{4.7 - V_{TH}}{R_1}\\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Using my example component values, this works out to about 12mA, which remains more or less constant over a wide range of supply voltages:

[image]

It doesn't start regulating current until the MOSFET's gate becomes sufficiently biased, which starts when the supply is about 5V in this case.

Bipolar junction transistors work better in this respect; with a low base-emitter junction voltage of 0.7V, the potential difference  created by D1 can be as small as 1V or so, and the transistor would then switch on and begin regulating at a much lower supply voltage.

Comment: The OP was looking for a voltage controlled current independent of supply.

Answer (score 0):

A very good current source can be made with an adjustable regulator like LM317 and a single resistor to set current.

[image: LM317 Current Source]
https://www.bristolwatch.com/ccs/LM317.htm

Voltage references similarly can be used as current sources:
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoaa46/snoaa46.pdf?ts=1661041267122

The LM334 is an adjustable current source:
https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/analog/article/21805826/whats-all-this-lm334-stuff-anyhow

As the OP wanted a voltage-controlled current source, I have simulated an NJFET that provides that function as a current sink. A PJFET should be able to provide a current source.

[image: Voltage Controlled Current JFET]

Here is avoltage controlled current source using a PJFET:

[image: Voltage Controlled Current JFET]

Comment: The OP was looking for a voltage controlled current independent of supply.